# SQL server Display Name of Max Values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the top 3 sick leavers per Site in my employee table. Im attempting to write a query to find the top sick leaver per site first.

Here is what I have but I can't seem to get it right
Here's what I have

```
select Site.SiteName,
[FullName] where MAX([SickLeaveTaken])
from Employee
left join Site
on(Employee.SiteID=Site.SiteID)
GROUP BY Site.SiteName;
GO
```

Comment: You seem to be aggregating by site, and I'm not sure why you thought to do this.  Please include some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Apologies, I'm doing it per site. I'll add some data now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get top 3 employees with max sick leave by using RANK function in SQL

```
select top 3 EmployeeID,SickLeaveTaken,s.SiteName,rn from 
(select e.EmployeeID,SickLeaveTaken,e.SiteID ,RANK() over(order by [SickLeaveTaken] 
desc ) as rn
from @Employee e )e
left join @Site s on e.SiteID=s.SiteID
order by rn desc
```

Comment: What happens if 5 employees happen to be tied for the most sick leave?  How many records would your query return in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table Employee contains the column `SickLeaveTaken` (although this is not normal) you need to sort descending the results and get TOP 3:

```
select TOP(3) WITH TIES
  s.SiteName, 
  e.FullName, 
  MAX(e.SickLeaveTaken) maxleave
from Site s inner join Employee e
on e.SiteID = s.SiteID
GROUP BY s.SiteName, e.FullName
ORDER BY MAX(e.SickLeaveTaken) DESC;
```